# ProgressView progress in TableViewCell is altered when table view is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiprogressview

In my app I have to show multiple progress views in a single `tableViewCell`, the progress as per actual to goal and it showing correctly when cell is loaded for the first time as per  image1

[image: image1]

but after scrolling the table the cell is visible like image2.

[image: image2]

The progress of the progress views is altered after scrolling the tableview. I have printed the progress values in `cellForRowAt` method and they are correct but the progress in progress view is being altered. I am setting the progressview progress in `cellForRowAt` method.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

@Bhavin Kansagara here is my code in `cellForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cellIdentifier = "myIdentifier"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? MyTableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? MyTableViewCell
        }

        let myDict = self.myArray[indexPath.row]
        let goalDict = myDict["goal"]!
        let actualDict = myDict["actual"]!

        for label in cell!.actualValueLabels {
            switch label.tag {
            case 0:
                label.text = String(actualDict["value1"]!)
            case 1:
                label.text = String(actualDict["value2"]!)
            case 2:
                label.text = String(actualDict["value3"]!)
            case 3:
                label.text = String(actualDict["value4"]!)
            case 4:
                label.text = String(actualDict["value5"]!)
            case 5:
                label.text = String(actualDict["total"]!)
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        for label in cell!.goalValueLabels {
            switch label.tag {
            case 0:
                label.text = String(goalDict["value1"]!)
            case 1:
                label.text = String(goalDict["value2"]!)
            case 2:
                label.text = String(goalDict["value3"]!)
            case 3:
                label.text = String(goalDict["value4"]!)
            case 4:
                label.text = String(goalDict["value5"]!)
            case 5:
                label.text = String(goalDict["total"]!)
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        let greenColor = UIColor(red: 146/255, green: 209/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1)
        let yellowColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 122/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        let value1Goal = goalDict["value1"]!
        let value1Actual = actualDict["value1"]!
        cell?.value1ProgressView.progressTintColor = value1Actual >= value1Goal ? greenColor : yellowColor
        if value1Goal == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value1ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value1Actual), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value1ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value1Actual)/Float(value1Goal), animated: true)
            }
        }
        let value2Goal = goalDict["value2"]!
        let value2Actual = actualDict["value2"]!
        cell?.value2ProgressView.progressTintColor = value2Actual >= value2Goal ? greenColor : yellowColor
        if value2Goal == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value2ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value2Actual), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value2ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value2Actual)/Float(value2Goal), animated: true)
            }
        }
        let value3Goal = goalDict["value3"]!
        let value3Actual = actualDict["value3"]!
        cell?.value3ProgressView.progressTintColor = value3Actual >= value3Goal ? greenColor : yellowColor
        if value3Goal == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value3ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value3Actual), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value3ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value3Actual)/Float(value3Goal), animated: true)
            }
        }
        let value4Goal = goalDict["value4"]!
        let value4Actual = actualDict["value4"]!
        cell?.value4ProgressView.progressTintColor = value4Actual >= value4Goal ? greenColor : yellowColor
        if value4Goal == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value4ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value4Actual), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value4ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value4Actual)/Float(value4Goal), animated: true)
            }
        }
        let value5Goal = goalDict["value5"]!
        let value5Actual = actualDict["value5"]!
        cell?.value5ProgressView.progressTintColor = value5Actual >= value5Goal ? greenColor : yellowColor
        if value5Goal == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value5ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value5Actual), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.value5ProgressView.setProgress(Float(value5Actual)/Float(value5Goal), animated: true)
            }
        }
        let totalGoal = goalDict["total"] as! Int
        let totalActual = actualDict["count"]!
        cell?.totalProgressView.progressTintColor = totalActual >= totalGoal ? greenColor : yellowColor
        if totalGoal == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.totalProgressView.setProgress(Float(totalActual), animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell?.totalProgressView.setProgress(Float(totalActual)/Float(totalGoal), animated: true)
            }
        }

        return cell!
    }

    else {
        //another cells are used in other sections
    }
}
```

here `myArray = [[String: [String: Int]]]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your code to point out the issue with ease.

Comment: You need to store progress value in your ModelClass and once progress value will update you also need to update that value in your model and always load value from model.

Comment: @BhavinKansagara did you have any solution as per the code I added? Thanks

Comment: Looking at your code, it's all well. but due to tableView reuse the cell, progress of one transferred to other. can you check for the Outlet's of Progressview in MyTableViewCell and change it to strong if it is previously weak. and rerun

Comment: i changed the outlets to strong and reran but the issue is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to handle this situations, You should try setting the different identifier for the cell's but that will affect your performance. after setting this approach, you should check for the performance of scrolling on your device.

```
let cellIdentifier = "myIdentifier_\(indexPath.section)_\(indexPath.row)"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? MyTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as? MyTableViewCell
}
```

This is not the best approach, but can help avoid the repeating process issue.

Try and share results.